# Storing factories instance

Tags: design-patterns

Let's say I have theses classes A (Client), B, C.

Class B needs to create an instance of Class C, then do some operations on that instance.

However, Class A needs to do some cleanup on that instance after Class B has run, but it is unable to do the creation of Class C for B as B as certain configuration options it needs to pass to C during creation.

What is the cleanest pattern for doing this?

I was thinking of having A create a Factory which B then calls `make` with its extra arguments. However, that would still not grant access to the instance of C to A (It is not viable just to return C).

```
Class A

    function do
        factory = new CFactory
        b.do(factory)

        // get c from somewhere
        c.doSomething
    end
end

Class B
    function do(factory)
        c = factory.make(some, extra, args)
        ...
        ...
        ...
        // Can not viablly return c or store a reference to it
    end
end

Class C
    function doSomething

    end
end
```

Comment: Showing some of your current code might help illuminate the problem.

Comment: @dbugger I have added some pseudo-code.

Comment: I'd argue that CFactory isn't really a factory if doesn't return a valid and useful instance of C.  The fact all this jumping around is needed strongly implies that all the objects involved need to be re-thought.

Comment: CFactory does return an instance of C, it is B that can not return the instance. I have currently added AOP to resolve this issue by using after on `make` to get the instance of C in A.